# Asp.Net Core Api reschedule Quartz.NET job

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, quartz.net

I have an Asp.Net Core Api application with one endpoint. I also configured Quartz.NET (3.6.2.) with one job, but without a trigger:

```
using Quartz;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
    q.AddJob<ReportJob>(opts => opts
        .WithIdentity(new JobKey("ReportJobKey"))
        .StoreDurably(true));
});
builder.Services.AddQuartzHostedService(q => q.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
```

The job itself does something and is described like this:

```
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class ReportJob : IJob
{
    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        // Some works...
       
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

I need to update the trigger in the controller method (if not, create it) for a one-time job launch in 1 minute. If there is one request to the controller, then the Job will be executed in a minute, if there are more requests, the Job start time will shift.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/report")]
public class ReportController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ISchedulerFactory _factory;

    public ReportController(ISchedulerFactory factory) => _factory = factory;
    
    [HttpPost("run")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateReportAsync(Guid id)
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = await _factory.GetScheduler();

        JobKey jobKey = new("ReportJobKey");

        TriggerKey triggerKey = new("ReportTriggerKey");
        
        var trigger = (ISimpleTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity(triggerKey)
            .StartAt(DateBuilder.FutureDate(1, IntervalUnit.Minute))
            .ForJob(jobKey)
            .Build();

        await scheduler.RescheduleJob(triggerKey, trigger);

        // if you uncomment, it will be executed immediately
        // await scheduler.TriggerJob(jobKey); 

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

My code above didn't work for me - Job will not be called. What ideas could there be?

Comment: Why are you rescheduling a one time job? You should be able to just schedule it i.e: `scheduler.ScheduleJob(trigger);`  or similar.

Comment: This is not what I need: I need the Job to work 1 minute after the last request to the controller.

Comment: The `ISimpleTrigger` in your code is a onetime job. You have the delay in minutes in the trigger specified. Calling `scheduler.ScheduleJob(trigger)` will schedule the job to start at the time specified in `StartAt` which is 1 minute in the future. The job will then delete itself automatically when completed. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Almost. A request was sent to the controller, the task started after 1 minute. But another request came (the minute has not yet come). The previous task should not be started - I start a new one (more precisely, the same one, but with a new time), again after 1 minute.

Comment: I see. Using unscheduling you can unschedule jobs by job key or triggerkey. From what I remember calling delete on a job that doesn't exist doesn't throw an exception so you should be fine just calling it before scheduling the new job. See more here on unscheduling http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/cookbook/UnscheduleJob.html

Comment: Offhand, adding `await scheduler.UnscheduleJob(triggerKey);` works fine together with `await scheduler.ScheduleJob(trigger);`